# JavaScript Array Auto Populates Based On Dropdown Selection?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have a question about a web app I'm considering making. I want to allow users to select an item from a dropdown list. For instance we'll say clothes. So they select an option from the dropdown list like: Shirt, Pants, Shoes.

From there, it will then auto-populate various input/text fields below such as prices.

Do I make one array with all of the options? Such as {'shirt', 'pants', 'shoes'}, or do I do: {'shirt', '14.99', 'red', 'tuesday'}

For instance if someone selected shirt, it would then populate the fields based on $14.99 for price, red for color, and Tuesday for date to wear.

OR do I do a different array for each individual field and just do if then statements like, "if 'shirt' === 'red', then [0]"

I'm lost on how to get started ( extremely inexperienced in JS, but figured I'd ask.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd make an array for each, shirt, pants, shoes, but I am also a database engineer so that makes sense. It's all what makes sense. One more array one take a ton of processing time. Read a couple JS tutorals, w3 is great so is coding bat.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense. I'm reading the W3 Documentation, and I could do the find() function for the dropdown selection... and then auto populate based on the if function stating if (function = find('string') then [array number like 3] which would populate based on the number in that individual array, and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing a small piece of code to give you an idea.
I found time and I also write select boxes.

```js
var dress, i, j, x = "";
dress = {
    "shirt": [
        { "product_name":"women shirt", "price": 25, "colors":[ "red", "green", "yellow" ] },
        { "product_name":"baby shirt", "price": 35, "colors":[ "red", "pink" ] },
        { "product_name":"man shirt", "price": 15,  "colors":[ "pink", "blue" ] }
    ]
}

for (i in dress.shirt) {
    x += "<h2>Product Name: " + dress.shirt[i].product_name +" > Price: "+ dress.shirt[i].price+"</h2>";
    for (j in dress.shirt[i].colors) {
        x += dress.shirt[i].colors[j] + "<br>";
    }
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```